# fontspec related font setting compiles on Linux, but not on Windows

Tags: xetex, texlive, fontspec, windows

I have this portion of code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath, fontspec}
\usepackage[math-style=TeX, bold-style=TeX]{unicode-math}

\setmathfont[StylisticSet=0]{xits-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range={\mathcal,\mathbfcal}, StylisticSet=1]{xits-math.otf}

\begin{document}
\[ p + q = 1 \]
\[ \mathcal{AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz} \]
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I'm selecting a stylistic set for `xits-math.otf`. I do this, to get a representation of calligraphic letters in math mode, that conforms to guidelines at my institute.

Now, Because of the line `\setmathfont[range={\mathcal,\mathbfcal}, StylisticSet=1]{xits-math.otf}` the document doesn't compile on Windows. On Linux, it does compile fine. When the line is commented out, it *does* compile on Windows as well.

I'm using TeXlive on both systems (Fedora 20 and Windows 7), with pretty much all packages installed, and I made sure, that `xits-math.otf` is found on both machines (on Windows, the files in question are installed into `C:\Windows\Fonts\`).

***Why?***

`xelatex` version on Linux:

> XeTeX 3.1415926-2.6-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2014/dev)

`xelatex` version on Windows:

> XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 (TeX Live 2014/W32TeX)

Comment: There's a chance that you have an updated fontspec version in one of these distributions; there is a known error that will be fixed shortly. If this is the case, load the fixltx2e package early to resolve the problem. If not, please add additional information, such as what the error message actually is.

Comment: @WillRobertson: Yes, it is the \dimexpr-error. The document works fine with `\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it does complain about `\dimexpr`, what should I do, to fix this (as an interim solution)?

Comment: Well as Will and me wrote already: load fixltx2e.

Comment: Erm, OK, I'll try as soon as I get back to that Windows system. Since this is a "well known" bug, any ideas when this will be fixed?

Comment: @polemon I'll hopefully upload a fix to CTAN tonight.